# want to see username besides power button

Tags: unity, 13.04

today I installed a fresh ubuntu 13.04 raring but when i logged in I saw the text that represents my username at the top-right corner of screen has gone!

but I want to see it again like 12.10 and 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Unity Tweak Tool to add this.

To install, it can be found in the Software Center, or through the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

In Unity Tweak Tool, under the "Unity" section at the top, click on "Panel". Then, in the bottom-right-hand corner should be a checkbox for "Show my name". Checking that should restore your name next to the power button.

Answer (score 2):

From a terminal

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true`

If you later want to remove

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false`